# Missing data and missing not at random

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

My outcome is a `child cognition scores (y)`. I will skip the exposure for now. My covariates are regular features like , `childsex, Mother's BMI, AgeAtAssessment, Mother's Alcohol consumption,  Mother's Tobacco use` and `Centers` where the subjects were recruited for study.

The general data distribution shows random missingness within most covariates and they are less than 5% which makes me feel good about using Multiple Imputation to impute for missing data.  However for this is one variable `Mother's BMI` subjects from `CenterD` did not submit any BMI data. So all women from this center (CenterD) have missing data.

How do I deal with this situation where missingess is random and between 5-10% except one Center that did not submit any data for one covriate `BMI` for subjects from their Center.  Any suggestions or advice is welcome. Thanks.

This is my test dataset

```
SampleData <- 
structure(list(gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female", 
"male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", 
"female", "male", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", 
"male", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", 
"female", "male", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", 
"male", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male", "female", "male", 
"female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", 
"female", "female", "male", "male", "female", "male", "female", 
"male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", 
"male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"female", "male", "female", "female", "male", "female", NA), 
    bmi_values = c("32.659", NA, "31.589", "22.85", "30.986", 
    NA, "23.771", NA, "29.4", "25.183", "22.197", "33.674", "26.443", 
    NA, NA, NA, "25.868", "23.36", NA, NA, "23.31", "17.816", 
    NA, "24.716", "24.085", "23.964", "32.564", "31.307", NA, 
    "25.504", "30.6", "26.664", NA, "27.496", "27.398", NA, "29.038", 
    NA, "16.285", "21.308", "25.031", "24.788", "23.495", "30.432", 
    NA, NA, "25.29", "19.269", "28.055", NA, "26.307", "23.129", 
    "22.813", NA, "15.691", "14.47", NA, "34.116", NA, "21.09", 
    "31.989", NA, "24.573", NA, "28.763", "21.631", NA, "23.339", 
    "26.472", "24.645", NA, "19.261", "32.442", "23.968", "24.337", 
    NA, "26.793", "26.669", NA, "18.854", NA, "18.431", "30.288", 
    NA, "25.874", "28.935", "23.52", "23.496", NA, "19.585", 
    "28.07", NA, "30.152", "23.456", "17.187", NA, "25.493", 
    "25.225", "25.19", "30.855"), age = c("51", "49", "30", "64", 
    "61", "52", "48", "36", "84", "40", "50", "41", "64", "50", 
    "54", "52", "31", NA, "41", "64", "69", "37", "54", "52", 
    "39", "23", "20", "31", "29", NA, "18", "28", "43", "60", 
    "61", "32", "35", "37", "20", "42", NA, "58", "84", "31", 
    "43", "35", "64", "22", "63", "60", "83", "19", "21", "28", 
    "78", "51", "79", "84", "36", NA, "30", "80", "85", "39", 
    "75", "41", "74", "28", "38", "36", "60", "69", "81", "58", 
    "37", "56", "54", "65", "38", "42", "77", "41", "61", "30", 
    "61", "50", "52", "68", "42", "74", "53", "45", "56", NA, 
    "25", "74", "42", "46", "19", "30"), Alcohol = c("Yes", "No", 
    "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
    "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "Yes", NA, "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "No", NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
    "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), Tobacco = c("Yes", "No", 
    "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "No", NA, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
    "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", NA, "Yes", "Yes", 
    "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No"), center = c("CenterB", 
    "CenterD", "CenterA", "CenterA", "CenterC", "CenterD", "CenterA", 
    "CenterD", "CenterB", "CenterB", "CenterC", "CenterA", "CenterA", 
    "CenterD", "CenterD", "CenterA", "CenterC", "CenterA", "CenterD", 
    "CenterD", "CenterB", "CenterC", "CenterD", "CenterB", "CenterA", 
    "CenterC", "CenterC", "CenterB", "CenterD", "CenterA", "CenterB", 
    "CenterA", "CenterD", "CenterB", "CenterA", "CenterD", "CenterC", 
    "CenterD", "CenterB", "CenterB", "CenterA", "CenterC", "CenterB", 
    "CenterA", "CenterC", "CenterD", "CenterB", "CenterA", "CenterA", 
    "CenterD", "CenterA", "CenterA", "CenterB", "CenterD", "CenterB", 
    "CenterC", "CenterD", "CenterC", "CenterD", "CenterA", "CenterA", 
    "CenterD", "CenterC", "CenterA", "CenterC", "CenterA", "CenterD", 
    "CenterC", "CenterC", "CenterA", "CenterD", "CenterC", "CenterB", 
    "CenterB", "CenterC", "CenterD", "CenterC", "CenterA", "CenterD", 
    "CenterB", "CenterD", "CenterB", "CenterB", "CenterD", "CenterA", 
    "CenterA", "CenterB", "CenterB", "CenterC", "CenterB", "CenterA", 
    "CenterD", "CenterC", "CenterC", "CenterA", "CenterD", "CenterB", 
    "CenterC", "CenterC", "CenterB")), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: (I assume the example data is a subset of the dataset you are working with.) Have you considered a Bayesian hierarchical analysis? I think it could work well here because the model will also learn about the "population of centers" and thus handle a whole center with missing BMI measurements.